# retrieve the ID parameter from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC I am trying to pass an optional ID parameter from one ActionResult method and I want to capture that ID in another ActionResult method. I currently have the following code but I still can't find a way to get the ID in the `Method2()`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Method1(SomeModel model)
{
    int someID = model.something.Id;
    .
    ..
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("Method2", new { userID = someID});
}
```

After clicking on a button on Method1's View page, the code will direct me to Method2 page and I will see something like this in my URL

`http://localhost:1234/myController/method2?userid=100` note that the `?userid=100` was sucessfully passed to the URL when `Method2` got called.

and this is my Method2. I am trying to get the `userid` but I can't.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Method2()
{
    **I want to get the userID from the URL**
}
```

I even tried to use `int? id` but still I am getting a null for id.

```
public ActionResult Method2(int? id)
{
    //id return null all the time
}
```

Any help on how I can get the `userid` in the URL in Method2()?

Comment: Use the Request.QueryString key value pair collection inside your ActionResult Method2() to get the user id

Comment: Add `userId` to the method signature. `public ActionResult Method2(int? userID)`.

Comment: Or just use `new { id= someID }` if the method is `public ActionResult Method2(int? id)` (the names of the parameters must match)

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I didn't use the matching parameter name. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your query string's variable name and actionresult variable name must match**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Method2(int userid)
{
    //your code        
}
```

or even

```
public ActionResult Method2(int? userid)
{
    //id return null all the time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value key value pair for userid is in the request querystring collection. To get it do something like the following:

```
if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
    if(Request.QueryString["userid"] != null)
    {
         int userId = (int)Request.QueryString["userid"];
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you makng ths so hard? don't cut an apple wth an axe you got knife for that

Comment: I don't believe what I posted is exactly hard in any way, in fact it shows another way of accomplishing what he is trying to do.

Comment: he messed with the querystring variable name thats all

Comment: Yes, he did. And your way works, but so does what I suggested.

Comment: I've used what I posted in my own development and I can assure you it does work.

Comment: you have to put your code inside actionresult and then what happens is when the url tries to find the actionresult with specifc name and parameters ?

Comment: If you are going to use the url like this: http://localhost:1234/myController/method2?userid=100, his action result doesn't even need to accept any parameters, this will be pulled out by using the Request.QueryString collection, after looking back at my project which I did something similar in, I realized you can't call ContainsKey on QueryString, but you can check to see if the value of QueryString["userid"] equals null and if not then you grab the value